# Integrating Helidon with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, helidon

Using [rest service using Helidon](https://www.baeldung.com/microservices-oracle-helidon#:%7E:text=Currently%2C%20Helidon%20provides%20the%20NettyWebServer,is%20based%20on%20Netty%20Core.&text=In%20this%20example%2C%20we%20configured,provided%20by%20the%20Config%20API)

Have created app using Helidon and rest services are available from Helidon.

i want to use spring jdbc template,dao Autowire features with Helidon and searched lot didn't find any article first of all is it right way ? Please suggest docs links

Answer (score 3):

Spring and Helidon are alternative frameworks indented for (mostly) the same purpose. They are two different worlds that will have problems coliding.
I don't think it's impossible to combine them, but it is at least impractical and bound to bring lots of problems like bean instantiation, classloader and so on with them.
I'd recommend you choose one of the two and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Helidon is not Spring so does not support these features.  It sounds like you want to write a Spring application instead.